# How to fix typeerror “a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'” while loading pbtxt file using label_map_util?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I'm trying to load the .pbtxt file using object detection util module label_map_util but I get an error as label_map_util as shown in the code

```
from models.research.object_detection.utils import label_map_util
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap("/content/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt")
```

I ger error as

```
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/content/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py in load_labelmap(path)
    170     try:
--> 171       text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
    172     except text_format.ParseError:

7 frames
ParseError: 7:1 : '<!DOCTYPE html>': Expected identifier or number, got <.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/content/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py in load_labelmap(path)
    171       text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
    172     except text_format.ParseError:
--> 173       label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)
    174   _validate_label_map(label_map)
    175   return label_map

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I downloaded the mscoco_label_map.pbtxt file from this link and the object detection model from this link

I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.0 version on a collab

How can I fix this and load the .pbtxt file successfully? any help or suggestion on this will be helpful thanks

Comment: Can you try `from object_detection.utils import label_map_util, 
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('/content/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'),
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a problem with labels text. Make sure they are all English utf-8 characters, and there are no problematic characters like ', e.g. in "person's hair".